# Images that are on the Imgur server can not be viewed

Tags: discussion, imgur

Here in my company there is a policy that limits me to seeing certain websites, which, to a certain extent, I agree with. Unfortunately, images that are on the Imgur domain (including https://i.stack.imgur.com) can not be viewed. I tried a technique where I add the term "cache:" at the beginning of the page address to try to see something, but I did not succeed.

Anyway, is there any technique that I can navigate and see the images? I do not think it is going against company policy, but there must be an unnecessary lock.